# Visual Studio - Killing Specific Processes on Stop Debug (Shift+F5)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a project that start up a few Processes when launched. The processes are stopped and destroyed in the appropriate destructors (or on the click of a button), and everything is fine.
My problem arises when I debug. Of course, when debugging, I won't always close my application "properly"; Most of the time, I will click the "Stop Debugging" button in Visual Studio (Shift+F5) or the thing will just crash. I these cases, I have to go and manually close the processes :(

Just wondering if there is an option in VS2010 Pro. that will allow me to kill the created processes when I stop debugging. I'm thinking of writing a Macro for this might work, but does VS2010 have a built-in feature for this? Kind of like the Custom Build steps, but for debugging!

Comment: This isn't limited to a debug session, this will also happen after you ship and the process dies on, say, an unhandled exception.  But without you around to kill the right processes.  You'll need to write code to protect against this.  Solves your debug problem too.

Comment: Well, with a shipped product, you can always try{}catch() the main and check for runaway processes to kill, just to be very safe. In which case stopping the debugger won't terminate them.
Also, the child processes "should" check regularly if the parent process is still running and terminate if it's not. This solves the problem, but adds a small-to-large overhead depending on how often it checks. But you are right, and I will eventually get to that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will take it from the silence that there is no such feature.
So here is the macro for it:

```
Sub StopDebugAndKillProcesses()
    Dim dbg As EnvDTE80.Debugger2 = DTE.Debugger
    dbg.Stop()
    Dim shell_string As String
    shell_string = "taskkill /F /IM TheProcessToKill.exe"
    Shell(shell_string)
End Sub
```

Assign it to a button, put it next to the original "Stop" button and your done.

Comment: Unfortunately no more macros in VS2012. I personally add a monitoring thread in the child process to monitor if the parent process is still alive. If the parent process dies, then the child process shutdown itself.